# Unable to assign property Text. string expected, got nil roblox error

Tags: lua, roblox

I have no idea how this is an error, can anyone help me out? This is supposed to be a global leaderboard, but nope, this error is ruining it. The line is new.ClickVal.Text = val. it used to be new.Value.Text = val, and i thought maybe it was because the game thought 'Value' was the actual VALUE of the text, which it was the name of a textlabel, so i changed it to 'ClickVal" and it still doesnt work. Thank you for helping out!!!

```
local sg = script.Parent
local sample = script:WaitForChild("Sample")
local sf = sg:WaitForChild("ScrollingFrame")
local ui = sf:WaitForChild("UI")

local dataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")

local dataStore = dataStoreService:GetOrderedDataStore("Leaderboard")

wait(10)
while true do
    for i,plr in pairs(game.Players:GetChildren()) do
        if plr.UserId>0 then
            local ps = game:GetService("PointsService")
        local w = plr.leaderstats.Clicks.Value
        if w then
            pcall(function()
                
                dataStore:UpdateAsync(plr.UserId,function(oldVal)
                    
                    return tonumber(w)
                end)
            end)
        end
    end
end
local smallestFirst = false
local numberToShow = 100
local minValue = 1
local maxValue = 10e100
local pages = dataStore:GetSortedAsync(smallestFirst, numberToShow, minValue, maxValue)

local top = pages:GetCurrentPage()
local data = {}
for a,b in ipairs(top) do
    local userId = b.key
    local points = b.Value
    local username = "[Failed To Load]"
    local s,e = pcall(function()
        username = game.Players:GetNameFromUserIdAsync(userId)
    end)
    if not s then
        warn("Error getting name for "..userId..". Error: "..e)
    end
    local image = game.Players:GetUserThumbnailAsync(userId, Enum.ThumbnailType.HeadShot, Enum.ThumbnailSize.Size150x150)
    
    table.insert(data,{username,points,image})
end
ui.Parent = script
sf:ClearAllChildren()
ui.Parent = sf
for number,d in pairs(data) do
    local name = d[1]
    local val = d[2]
    local image = d[3]
    local color = Color3.new(1,1,1)
    if number == 1 then
        color = Color3.new(1,1,0)
    elseif number == 2 then
        color = Color3.new(0.7,0.7,0.7)
    elseif number == 3 then
        color = Color3.fromRGB(166, 112, 0)
    end
    local new = sample:Clone()
    new.Name = name
    new.LayoutOrder = number
    new.Image.Image = image
    new.Image.Place.Text = number
    new.Image.Place.TextColor3 = color
    new.PName.Text = name
    new.ClickVal.Text = val
    new.ClickVal.TextColor3 = color
    new.PName.TextColor3 = color
    new.Parent = sf
end
wait()
sf.CanvasSize = UDim2.new(0,0,0,ui.AbsoluteContentSize.Y)

wait(10)
```

end

if you have the fix then post it please thanks!

Comment: Heyo, I don't think we've got enough information to help you. `val=d[2]`, which is mapped to points in `table.insert(data,{username,points,image})`. And `local points = b.Value` but b comes from a page from your ordered data store. Could you share what the format of this data is supposed to look like?

Comment: idk what that means, to be honest, i just used a script from a youtube video.

Comment: What happens if you print out `top` after the line `local top = pages:GetCurrentPage()`? What shows up with `print(top)`?